# Loopback 4 - Is it possible to define id property's length?

Tags: mysql, indexing, loopbackjs, varchar, loopback4

Using LB4 + MySQL DB through loopback-connector-mysql to create tables on DB.

A
{id: string, name: string}

| id | names |
| --- | --- |
| 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae4d | John |
| 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae3d | Marie |

B
{id: string, aId:string, name: string}

| id | aId | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae2d | 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae4d | Eve |
| 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae1d | 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae4d | Ronald |
| 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae0d | 0007bc40-814b-11ec-8128-4df48bd1ae3d | Philipe |

To create those models, I've used this code:

**A**

```
export class Payroll extends Entity {
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        id: true,
        defaultFn: 'uuid',
    })
    id: string;

    
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        length: 64,
    })
    name: string;
}
```

**B**

```
export class Payroll extends Entity {
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        id: true,
        defaultFn: 'uuid',
    })
    id: string;


    @belongsTo(() => A)
    aId: string;
    
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        length: 64,
    })
    name: string;
}
```

On both tables, id is a VARCHAR(255), although it only needs a VARCHAR(36)
On B table, aId is a VARCHAR(512), which is even worse... This could be solved by defining aId as follows:

`@belongsTo(() => A, undefined, { length: 36, }) aId: string;`

Now, b.aId is a VARCHAR(36), but then i get the error following error:

> Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Referencing column 'aId' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_a_b_aId' are incompatible", because both VARCHAR have different size.

How can I tell LB4 which length (in this example, 36)of the ID property I want on DB?

Thank you

Comment: and what has id for a length, check that also

Comment: Does it have any way to generate a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: @nbk I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @RickJames, a constraint could be generated in many ways (for example, with the "required: true"), but it's not clear to me how that relates to my question

Comment: @AlexCorregidor i mean that you should shpow us the create table from A and B , because the datatypes seem to be different

Comment: @nbk The CREATE query is generated internally by LB4. The question is how to tell LB4 that I want it to create the ID field with X VARCHAR length. Maybe I've been unclear, I'll edit the question

Comment: (Alas, using a framework requires learning two databases -- the underlying db (MySQL) and the framework's rendition of such.)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.. I prefer to use fixed char guid - old habits ;)

```
//// For ID (Primary key)
@property({
  type: 'string',
  id: true,
  defaultFn: 'uuidv4',
  dataType: 'char',
  limit: 36,
})
id?: string;

//// for relations
@belongsTo(
  () => RelatedModel,
  {},   // Relation Meta
  {     // Property Meta
    dataType: 'char',
    limit: 36
  }
)
ForeignKeyId: string;
```

Comment: This works on "@belongsTo", but on "@property", it keeps creating the id as a VARCHAR(255) on DB

Comment: @AlexCorregidor, it must be some other issue as this works fine for me.. I am using mysql db with mysql-connector.  pls share some of your code if possible.